# Determine whether $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \left(\sqrt[3]{n^2+5}-\sqrt[3]{n^2+1}\right)$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Determine whether the series converges $$\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty } \left(\sqrt[3]{n^2+5}-\sqrt[3]{n^2+1}\right).$$

By using the identity $a^3 - b^3 = (a - b) \cdot (a^2 + ab + b^2)$, we get $$\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4}{ \sqrt[3]{(n^2 + 5)^2} + \sqrt[3]{n^4} \cdot \sqrt[3]{1+ \frac{6}{n^2} + \frac{5}{n^4}} +\sqrt[3]{(n^2+1)^2}}.$$

I guess that I should use the comparison test for proving that my series converges. But what should I compare my series to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct, but it can be simplified with a little more effort (and without complicated algebraic issues).

Recall that for $m>1$, $\sqrt[m]{1+x}= 1+\frac{x}{m}+o(x)$ as $x\to 0$. Hence, more generally, if $a\not= b$ and $d>0$ then
$$\sqrt[m]{n^d+a}-\sqrt[m]{n^d+b}=n^{d/m}\left(\sqrt[m]{1+a/n^d}-\sqrt[m]{1+b/n^d}+o(1/n^d)\right)\\=n^{d/m}\left(\frac{a}{n^d}-\frac{b}{n^d}+o(1/n^d)\right)\sim \frac{a-b}{n^{(m-1)d/m}}$$
and the series 
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}^{\infty}\left(\sqrt[m]{n^d+a}-\sqrt[m]{n^d+b}\right)$$
is convergent iff $\frac{(m-1)d}{m}>1$ that is $d>\frac{m}{m-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

It follows from your computations that the quotient between the general term of your series and $1/n^{\frac43}$ is finite and non null. Since the sreies$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^\frac43}$$converges, so does your series.

Answer (score 0):

Using identity $(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)=a^3-b^3$ and inequalities $\sqrt[3]{n^2+5}> \sqrt[3]{n^2+1}> \sqrt[3]{n^2}$

$$(\sqrt[3]{n^2+5}-\sqrt[3]{n^2+1})\times\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{n^2+5}^2+\sqrt[3]{n^2+1}\sqrt[3]{n^2+5}+\sqrt[3]{n^2+1}^2}{\sqrt[3]{n^2+5}^2+\sqrt[3]{n^2+1}\sqrt[3]{n^2+5}+\sqrt[3]{n^2+1}^2}=\dfrac{4}{\sqrt[3]{n^2+5}^2+\sqrt[3]{n^2+1}\sqrt[3]{n^2+5}+\sqrt[3]{n^2+1}^2}\leq\dfrac{4}{4\sqrt[3]{n^4}}$$
then use [comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_test) or [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence).

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt[3]{(n^2 + 5)^2} \sim n^{4/3}$$

since, $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt[3]{(n^2 + 5)^2}}{n^{4/3}}= \lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[3]{( 1+ \frac{5}{n^2})^2} =1$$
similarly,

$$ \sqrt[3]{n^4}\cdot\sqrt[3]{1+ \frac{6}{n^2} + \frac{5}{n^4}}\sim \sqrt[3]{n^4}~~~and~~~\sqrt[3]{(n^2 + 1)^2} \sim n^{4/3}$$

Thus, $$ \frac{4}{ \sqrt[3]{(n^2 + 5)^2} + \sqrt[3]{n^4} \cdot \sqrt[3]{1+ \frac{6}{n^2} + \frac{5}{n^4}} +\sqrt[3]{(n^2+1)^2}}\sim \frac{4}{3n^{4/3}}$$

the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{4}{3n^{4/3}}$$
converges so the series which entails the converges of

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{4}{ \sqrt[3]{(n^2 + 5)^2} + \sqrt[3]{n^4} \cdot \sqrt[3]{1+ \frac{6}{n^2} + \frac{5}{n^4}} +\sqrt[3]{(n^2+1)^2}}<\infty$$